# Sorting a multi-dimensional array by the sequence of another array

Tags: php, sorting, arrays

Consider the following array:

```
$main_array = array();
$main_array[0] = array('location'=> array('France', 'Germany'), 'random_number'=> array('6520'));
$main_array[1] = array('location'=> array('Italy', 'Switzerland'), 'random_number'=> array('3245'));
$main_array[2] = array('location'=> array('Portugal', 'Spain'), 'random_number'=> array('9981'));
$main_array[3] = array('location'=> array('Turkey', 'Greece'), 'random_number'=> array('1098'));
```

I want to sort this array by the value of `random_number[0]` key and based on the **sequence** of the following array:

```
$sequenced = array('3245','1098','6520','9981');
```

So the final sorted array would look like:

```
$final_array = array();
$final_array[0] = array('location'=> array('Italy', 'Switzerland'), 'random_number'=> array('3245'));
$final_array[1] = array('location'=> array('Turkey', 'Greece'), 'random_number'=> array('1098'));
$final_array[2] = array('location'=> array('France', 'Germany'), 'random_number'=> array('6520'));
$final_array[3] = array('location'=> array('Portugal', 'Spain'), 'random_number'=> array('9981'));
```

Any idea how that would be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sorter($array, $sequence){
  $tmp = array();
  foreach($sequence as $s){
    foreach($array as $a){
      if($a[random_number][0] == $s){ 
        array_push($tmp, $a);
        break;
      }   
    }   
  }
  return $tmp;
}

$final_array = sorter($main_array, $sequenced);
```